# Make a laser beam effect with Ogre and a BillboardChain

Tags: sprites, ogre

http://www.lpi.usra.edu/lunar/missions/apollo/apollo_15/images/laser_beam_lg.gif

I want to be able to such an effect, but I don't really know how the BillboardChain class works or how I can use it, examples for this class seems to be rare.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
BillboardChain bbchain;
bbchain.addChainElement(BillboardChain::Element(Vector3(0,0,0), 10, 0, ColourValue(1, 0, 0)));
```

The main reason it was not working for me is because I did not set a high enough width.

Comment: I can't tell if this is supposed to be an "I have found the answer to my own question" post or a "clarification of my original question" post -- if the former you should mark it as the answer (I think you can accept your own answers) and if the latter it should be a comment or edit to the original question.

Comment: yes, but I had to wait for marking it as an answer, aqll done now !

Answer (score 2):

I have created an impressive laser by using particles, here is an example of what a laser particle script would look like:

```
particle_system Space/Laser
{
    material        Examples/Flare
    particle_width  3
    particle_height 3
    cull_each       false
    quota           1000000
    billboard_type  point
    local_space true

    // Area emitter
    emitter Point
    {
       angle           0
       emission_rate   500
       time_to_live_min 1000
       time_to_live_max 1000
       direction       0 0 -1
       velocity       1000
       colour 1.0 0.27 0.0
    }
}
```

Simply create a particle system using this script, attach to its own node, and toggle visibility on the node to make the laser appear/disappear.

This will create a nice Orange laser beam where you can change the size by editing the particle_width and particle_height attributes. To change the length of the laser edit the time_to_live_min and time_to_live_max attributes but make sure they are the same value.

The material Examples/Flare comes with the OgreSDK by default so you don't have to worry about it (It just uses a nice flare image that the particle script will re-color and use).

Be sure to save it as a .particle file

Answer (score 1):

The closest thing I have seen to this effect is [this](http://www.ogre3d.org/forums/viewtopic.php?p=304338)

There is also [this thread](http://www.ogre3d.org/forums/viewtopic.php?f=2&t=46870) that asks the exact same question. It only has 3 replies, but probably worth watching (unless of course you asked this question :P)

Comment: Why the downvote?